# Android gradle error(30.0) : gradle DSL method not found : compile()

Tags: android, android-studio

There is some error in compile error in build.gradle file. when i am synchronise the code there is something missing in the compile() method and mention an error (30,0).

```
build.gradle(project) : 

dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
        //classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

AND build.gradle(module) CODE IS :

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
}


//add library
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.6.2'
```

Comment: Error:(30, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()'
Possible causes:The project 'LetsChat' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.

Comment: call below 2 libraries in dependencies  section

Comment: thanks, there is an error in my mainActivity.java , there is unresolved symbol R , please suggest me how can i handle it.

Comment: Clean-Rebuild and import R